# Adding new rows, filling those with a consecutive year and 0s in the variable column

Tags: r

I've got a 3 columns table (year, ID, variable). For every individual ID I need add a new row with the following year and a 0 in the variable column.The difficulty for me is that every ID has got different number of rows (years).

This is may original table:

```
ID  year    var
1   1998    2
1   1999    5
1   2000    6
1   2001    6
1   2002    6
2   1998    12
2   1999    12
3   1998    5
3   1999    5
3   2000    4
```

... and this is what I need:

```
ID  year    var
1   1998    2
1   1999    5
1   2000    6
1   2001    6
1   2002    6
1   2003    0
2   1998    12
2   1999    12
2   2000    0
3   1998    5
3   1999    5
3   2000    4
3   2001    0
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the data:

```
test <- read.table(textConnection("ID  year    var
1   1998    2
1   1999    5
1   2000    6
1   2001    6
1   2002    6
2   1998    12
2   1999    12
3   1998    5
3   1999    5
3   2000    4"),header=TRUE)
```

Add the rows in:

```
do.call(rbind,by(test,test$ID,function(x) rbind(x,c(x$ID[1],max(x$year)+1,0))))
```

The result:

```
     ID year var
1.1   1 1998   2
1.2   1 1999   5
1.3   1 2000   6
1.4   1 2001   6
1.5   1 2002   6
1.6   1 2003   0
2.6   2 1998  12
2.7   2 1999  12
2.3   2 2000   0
3.8   3 1998   5
3.9   3 1999   5
3.10  3 2000   4
3.4   3 2001   0
```

Answer (score 5):

A data.table solution (for syntax more than memory efficiency)

```
library(data.table)
# assuming your data is in the data.frame dd
DT <- data.table(dd)

DT[,list(year = c(year,max(year)+1), var = c(var,0)),by = ID]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another solution using just the base package

```
DF <- read.table(textConnection("ID  year    var
1   1998    2
1   1999    5
1   2000    6
1   2001    6
1   2002    6
2   1998    12
2   1999    12
3   1998    5
3   1999    5
3   2000    4"), header=TRUE)

foo <- split(DF, DF["ID"])
addone <- function(x){
    last <- tail(x,1)
    last$year<-last$year+1
    last$var <- 0
    rbind(x,last)
    }
do.call(rbind, lapply(foo, addone))
```

... and the output:

```
      ID year var
1.1    1 1998   2
1.2    1 1999   5
1.3    1 2000   6
1.4    1 2001   6
1.5    1 2002   6
1.51   1 2003   0
2.6    2 1998  12
2.7    2 1999  12
2.71   2 2000   0
3.8    3 1998   5
3.9    3 1999   5
3.10   3 2000   4
3.101  3 2001   0
```